# Ruby: checking array for unique values and also returning minimum distance (haversine formula)

Tags: ruby, csv, unique, haversine

Having a hard time wrap my head around this.

I have two CSV's that make up a fiberoptic network: one for latitude, one for longitude. These were pulled from a KMZ file and both CSV's consist of 170k rows each due to the poorly built KMZ.

I have a CSV of potential customers that I want to compare against the fiber network. If the minimum distance (calculated using the Haversine formula), is less than 5280 feet, it'll print that out to the output csv file.

I've been with successful with this in the past when there aren't so many lat/long pairs: 20k in the past, but now we have 170k. The output csv file gets massive, as you can imagine: 3 million rows and counting.

Then what I would have to do is do a check (generally using MySQL MIN() function, but I'm sure there's a better way) to return the minimum distance per address and group by address: since you really only care about the minimum distance, per address. You don't want multiple rows for each address.

```
require 'csv'
require 'haversine'

#this could be put into one file, works as is
fib_lat = CSV.read("swfl_fiber_lat.csv")
fib_long = CSV.read("swfl_fiber_long.csv")

#use zip to read both arrays at the same time
fib_coords = fib_lat.map(&:last).zip(fib_long.map(&:last))

#multiple column CSV with customer data, headers turned on
customers = CSV.read("swfl_1a_geocoded.csv", headers:true)

CSV.open('swfl-output-data-within-1mile.csv','w', :write_headers=> true, :headers => ['First Name','Last Name','Latitude','Longitude','Feet to Fiber','Address','City','State','Zip','County','Company','Title Code Description','PrimarySIC6 Description','Business Status Code Description','Phone Number','Tollfree Phonenumber','EmployeeSize Location Description','Sales Volume Location Decode','Telecommunications Expense','Email Address']) do |csv_object|
    fib_coords.each do |fib_lat, fib_long|
        customers.each do |cust|       
            if (Haversine.distance(cust[2].to_f, cust[3].to_f, fib_lat.to_f, fib_long.to_f).to_feet < 5280)
                data_out = ["#{cust[0]},#{cust[1]},#{cust[2].to_f},#{cust[3].to_f}, #{Haversine.distance(cust[2].to_f, cust[3].to_f, fib_lat.to_f, fib_long.to_f).to_feet.round(2)},#{cust[5]},#{cust[6]},#{cust[7]},#{cust[8]},#{cust[9]},#{cust[10]},#{cust[11]},#{cust[12]},#{cust[13]},#{cust[14]},#{cust[15]},#{cust[16]},#{cust[17]},#{cust[18]}"]            
                csv_object << data_out
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I'm trying to think of a way to return the customer (maybe using `.uniq` `arr#min` and only the minimum address per customer without shoving that into the output CSV. Then, if there is indeed a distance below 5,280 and an associated customer, only put that into the output CSV array.

In regards to the psuedocode: if distance is the minimum per customer, make sure that customer value is unique, then shove that into the output CSV. Just not 100% on how to implement this in my flurry of loops.

Any and all insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, where are your performance issues? I'm going to assume its not in calculating `fib_coords` but in looping through the `customers`. There are a couple of changes I would make:

1) I would not read the whole customers CSV file into memory in one go but loop through the `customers` CSV file using the `CSV::for_each` method. Loading the whole CSV file is probably using a fair bit of memory which could be better used for the `fib_coords` array. This means reversing the order of `customers` and `fib_coords` loops.

2) Secondly, you can avoid searching the whole `fib_coords` array. If you sort by the first column so that it is in latitudinal order, calculate the minimum possible latitude (`customer.latitude - 5280ft`), find the first potential match in `fib_coords` using `bsearch` which is much faster than a linear search and loop through `fib_coords` from there until the latitude in `fib_coords` is out of range ( `> customer.latitude + 5280ft`).

Comment: The main performance issue is just having a monster output CSV file. 3-4million records and trying to open that in excel is a nightmare (and large in file size, close to 0.5gb if not more). Then what I would do is insert all those rows into a MySQL table, and use MIN() on feet_to_fiber and group by address. Heading to bed here but will try your approach first thing in the morning.

Comment: Are you saying that you have 3 to 4 million customers? The length of the output file should not matter, though processing that many customers might. If you are trying to do further processing then it does sound like a Database would be a good idea though I would consider something like `Postgres` which has some extensions for handling geographic co-ordinates. I have also had success using ElasticSearch for this.

Comment: The initial `swfl_1a_geocoded.csv` is ~10,000 customers. What's happening is that each customer in the aforementioned csv running through EVERY lat/long pair in the fiber, therefore returning multiple results in the output CSV. So, Jane Doe at XYZ address may have 150 output results under 5,280 feet. But I only care about the Jane Doe at XYZ which is the minimum of all those results under 5,280 feet. So I'm trying to avoid outputting duplicate customers to the the output file, and do some unique-ness style validation via Ruby.

Comment: As I said in my point (2) I would put the customers loop on the outside. If the lat/long pairs are sorted you can then loop through a minimal set of them and find the one with the minimum distance using a variation of the standard minimum code.